# CLR 4.0 inlining policy? (maybe bug with MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)

Tags: assemblies, clr, .net-4.0, inline, jit

I've testing some new CLR 4.0 behavior in method inlining (cross-assembly inlining) and found some strage results:

**Assembly ClassLib.dll**:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace ClassLib
{
  public static class A
  {
    static readonly MethodInfo GetExecuting =
      typeof(Assembly).GetMethod("GetExecutingAssembly");

    public static Assembly Foo(out StackTrace stack) // 13 bytes
    {
      // explicit call to GetExecutingAssembly()
      stack = new StackTrace();
      return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    }

    public static Assembly Bar(out StackTrace stack) // 25 bytes
    {
      // reflection call to GetExecutingAssembly()
      stack = new StackTrace();
      return (Assembly) GetExecuting.Invoke(null, null);
    }

    public static Assembly Baz(out StackTrace stack) // 9 bytes
    {
      stack = new StackTrace();
      return null;
    }

    public static Assembly Bob(out StackTrace stack) // 13 bytes
    {
      // call of non-inlinable method!
      return SomeSecurityCriticalMethod(out stack);
    }

    [SecurityCritical, MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    static Assembly SomeSecurityCriticalMethod(out StackTrace stack)
    {
      stack = new StackTrace();
      return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    }
  }
}
```

**Assembly ConsoleApp.exe**

```
using System;
using ClassLib;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("runtime: {0}", Environment.Version);

    StackTrace stack;
    Console.WriteLine("Foo: {0}\n{1}", A.Foo(out stack), stack);
    Console.WriteLine("Bar: {0}\n{1}", A.Bar(out stack), stack);
    Console.WriteLine("Baz: {0}\n{1}", A.Baz(out stack), stack);
    Console.WriteLine("Bob: {0}\n{1}", A.Bob(out stack), stack);
  }
}
```

**Results:**

```
runtime: 4.0.30128.1

Foo: ClassLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
   at ClassLib.A.Foo(StackTrace& stack)
   at Program.Main()

Bar: ClassLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
   at ClassLib.A.Bar(StackTrace& stack)
   at Program.Main()

Baz:
   at Program.Main()

Bob: ClassLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
   at Program.Main()
```

So questions are:

- Why JIT does not inlined `Foo` and `Bar` calls as `Baz` does? They are lower than 32 bytes of IL and are good candidates for inlining.
- Why JIT inlined call of `Bob` and inner call of `SomeSecurityCriticalMethod` that is marked with the `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]` attribute?
- Why `GetExecutingAssembly` returns a valid assembly when is called by inlined `Baz` and `SomeSecurityCriticalMethod` methods? I've expect that it performs the stack walk to detect the executing assembly, but stack will contains only `Program.Main()` call and no methods of `ClassLib` assenbly, to `ConsoleApp` should be returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CLR 4.0 has ETW events for most of things and here is the ETW trace for [Jit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff356158(VS.100).aspx) which should give out MethodJitInliningFailed reason and [here](http://naveensrinivasan.com/2010/03/17/using-clr-4-0-event-tracing-for-windows-etw-along-with-application-etw/) is how you view the trace information